# Chrome: Solving limited number of WebSockets (possibly with localStorage)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, websocket, local-storage

According to this post https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429419 as well as some testing I did to verify the limit is real - I understand that number of WebSockets I can open is limited.

Problem is that I sometimes need more than 30 websockets, because a user might open 30 tabs.

I was wondering what would be the best possible way of maybe sharing a pool of webSockets between different tabs. Here are some ideas I had in mind, and I would love to hear other possible ideas:

1. Allocate a webSocket pool in one main window, as a globally reachable element and then make sure all other tabs are children of that main page. Then I can use an inter-tab communication:

   `window.parent...`

Problem is that not all tabs are created as child windows of the main window, and that main window might be closed.

2. Allocate a webSocket pool somehow "in the local storage" - I am not too familiar with the local storage, but I think that at the very least it can hold somehow a reference to a master tab that is currently managing the webSockets. Every once in a while, other tabs try to set themselves as a master tab.

I know its sounds awful and cumbersome. But how possible is it to write a thread/proccess safe code when accessing the local storage? Any example will be appreciated.

3. Would love to hear any other suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 won't work, because LocalStorage is limited to string types.

I would recommend [looking at ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

> A single service worker can control many pages. Each time a page within your scope is loaded, the service worker is installed against that page and operates on it.

This sounds pretty close to what you want. Register a ServiceWorker that simply accepts messages and rebroadcasts them to clients - any page from your domain. So you can have one main page that creates the WebSocket connection, and every time it gets a push it will broadcast a message through the ServiceWorker messaging system. Other tabs can pick up on it as needed.

Alternatively, you could use a [shared WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) on the same principle. Just install it as a messaging system that broadcasts the messages from your WebSocket.

These aren't exactly the intended uses for these technologies... but if it works it works.

Comment: That being said, I don't think it's worth the time and effort to handle this extremely unlikely case. If you do anything, just alert the user that the websocket failed to connect. Anybody who has 30 tabs of the same page open deserves it to break.